# Php get basename of files in directory

Tags: php

I would like to create a links to all files in a specific directory. Example

```
Directory: /account contains;

user/
data/
register.txt
login.txt
instructions.docx
```

I would like to have php generate:

```
<a href="action.php?action=register.txt">register</a>
<a href="action.php?action=login.txt">login</a>
```

Preferably only create link of the .txt files.

I have this code:

```
<?php
 if ($handle = opendir('account')) {
 while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
 {
    if (($file != ".") 
     && ($file != ".."))
    {
        $test=`basename "$file"`; //this is line 8
        $thelist = '<a href="action.php?action='.$file.'">'.$test.'</a>';
    }
   }



   closedir($handle);
  } 
  ?>

 <P>List of files:</p>
 <UL>
 <P><?=$thelist?></p>
 </UL>
```

But it gives this error:

```
 Warning: shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons in /public_html/directory/checkit.php on line 8
```

And even if it would work it would display even files that do not have the .txt extension. 
(I know that the security reasons error can frequently be resolved by changing some php settings, or changing some permissions? But I know there is a way to do this without changing all my settings).

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=get+filename+without+extension+php

Comment: I'm able to get filename without extension, I was only wondering why my code didn't work, and how to limit the displayed files to only .txt files.

Comment: because you are using backticks but **"shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons"** obviously.

Comment: `$file` is already "basenamed"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use scandir() to get the content of a folder:

```
$theList = '';
$content = scandir('account');
foreach($content as $aFileInIt) {
    // skip files that do not end on ".txt"
    if(!preg_match('/(\.txt)$/i', $aFileInIt))
         continue;
    // save a-elements to variable
    // UPDATE: take the file's basename as the linktext
    $theList .= '<li><a href="action.php?action='.$aFileInIt.'">'.str_ireplace('.txt', '', $aFileInIt).'</a></li>';
}
```

And later, in order to have a correct UL-element:

```
echo '<ul>'.$theList.'</ul>';
```

Comment: Hello, this code will return <a href="action.php?action=register.txt">register.txt</a> So the link text willno contain the basename, but the full file name

Comment: I updated the answer to get the file's name without the extension.

Comment: Thank you! But I'm getting a: Fatal error: Call to undefined function stri_replace() on line 10 any idea?

Comment: It's str_ireplace(), sorry. Corrected the answer above.

Comment: No problem, it's already amazing that you help me this way. It's working!

Answer (score 4):

Replace the line

```
$test=`basename "$file"`; //this is line 8
```

by

```
$test=basename("$file");
```

Read Docs [basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

Comment: Strange anough, this could only returns (in the example): <a href="action.php?action=data">data</a>, So no files, only one directory (not even both). Any thoughts?

Comment: So you should direct use of it like `$test=$file;`

Answer (score 0):

Use `GlobIterator` instead ...

```
$fs = new GlobIterator(__DIR__.'/*.txt');
foreach ($fs as $file) {
    printf("<a href=\"action.php?action=%s\">%s</a> <br />\n", 
           urlencode($file),
           $file->getBasename(".txt"));
}
```

**Note** there are a lot of security implications to passing the full file path to `action=`, I think it's a bad design and not a good idea.

Just pass the `file name` and a `security token` instead

Comment: thank you for your help, but also for your answer: this will return <a href="action.php?action=register.txt">register.txt</a> So it link text will still contain .txt

Answer (score 0):

Use [glob](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function.

```
$directory = 'PATH_TO_YOUR_DIRECTORY' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

foreach( glob( $directory . "*.txt" ) as $filename ) {
  if( ! is_dir( $filename ) ) {
    echo basename( $filename ) . "\n";
  }
}
```